# Are there any guidelines on sharding a data set?

Tags: tensorflow

Are there any guidelines on choosing the number of shard files for a data set, or the number of records in each shard?

In the examples of using `tensorflow.contrib.slim`,

- there are roughly `1024` records in each shard of *ImageNet* data set.([tensorflow/models/inception](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception))
- there are roughly `600` records in each shard of *flowers* data set. ([tensorflow/models/slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/datasets/download_and_convert_flowers.py))

Do the number of shard files and the number of records in each shard has any impact on the training and the performance of the trained model?

To my knowledge, if we don't split the data set into multiple shards, it will be not quite random for shuffling data as the `capacity` of the `RandomShuffleQueue` may be less than the size of the data set.

Are there any other advantages of using multiple shards?

---

Update

[The documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/) says

> If you have more reading threads than input files, to avoid the risk that you will have two threads reading the same example from the same file near each other.

Why can't we use 50 threads to read from 5 files?

Comment: For huge datasets, 100MB per file is a good number. Small enough to copy to local machine to inspect it, but not so small as to overwhelm file descriptor tables. The comment in docs talks about N read ops/N threads vs 1 read op/N threads. In the later case, since reading op is stateful, N threads will be causing sequential file reads which is good for buffering. Using N read ops can trigger N disk seeks for N reads

Comment: Thank you @YaroslavBulatov. 

What does 'overwhelm file descriptor tables' means? To my knowledge, when a process open 10 files using 10 threads, the OS will create 10 descriptors to the table. Does the number of file descriptor's entries in the table relate to the number of shard files?

I have no idea what 'risk' (in the documentation >..., to avoid the risk that ...) means.

Comment: I meant tables on disk. There are usually limits on how many files you can have on a filesystem and on a directory, so if your files are too small, you could have too many of them for a huge dataset. The `risk` there is that if your threads end up reading the same files and same entries, your learning will not be as fast, as it could be if those were different files

Answer (score 1):

The newer(2.5) version of Tensorflow has shard feature for dataset.
Find the below sample code from [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=nightly#shard)

```
A = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
B = A.shard(num_shards=3, index=0)
list(B.as_numpy_iterator())
```

When reading a single input file, you can shard elements as follows

```
d = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(input_file)
d = d.shard(num_workers, worker_index)
```